# How to alter current url in AMP HTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, amp-html

In my website,  filtering of products is done server side by alterining the URLS, 
ie. by adding `?q=alpha+beta+gama` at the end of the URL if the category is to be filtered for products containing tags alpha, beta & gama

*I want to remove "beta" from the url should someone press a button.*

> Seems easy in non-amp pages by using javascript, but I cant find a way
>   to do it in amp.

**Is there a script that can fiind current url and remove some keywords from them based?**

I am planning to achieve this with a form. The form will have multiple inputs. On pressing submit button, the input fields in the form will be grabbed and appending to current url.
**Situation 1:**

```
The current url is website.com/?view=amp
Desirable url is website.com/?view=amp&q=alpha+beta+gama
```

**Situation 2**

```
Current url is website.com/?view=amp&q=alpha+beta+gama+delta
Second desirable URL is website.com/?view=amp&q=alpha+gama
```

Comment: This seems a use case for [`amp-link-rewriter`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-link-rewriter/). Have you tried it?

Comment: This does not solve my purpose

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per your use-case, you can simply use [`amp-bind`](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind/) to keep updating the URL in case user adds/changes default input value.

e.g.

```html
<label>Username
    <input name="username" on="change:AMP.setState({name: event.value})"/>
</label>
<a href="example.com/default-url" [href]="'example.com/default-url?name=' + name">Submit</a>
```

So, you need to provide a default URL as **`href`** value by default and **`[href]`** will update the default URL when any change on the input box is **made** (amp-bind works only when elements having AMP actions are triggered, remove). You can read more about the actions(i.e. any change) for making URL change [here](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/).

Answer (score 4):

We can't read current url and manipulate it in AMP.

### What is solution to create dynamic url (or links) in AMP?

We should have a state strategy to create dynamic url in AMP. We should render default state in server side and create dynamic url when states change.
for example:

Default states (rendered in server side):

```html
<amp-state id="filters">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "alpha": "",
      "beta": "",
      "gama": ""
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

Dynamic url base on states:

```html
<a href="website.com/?view=amp" data-amp-bind-href="'website.com/?view=amp&q=' + filters.alpha + (filters.beta ? '+' + filters.beta : '') + (filters.gama ? '+' + filters.gama : '')">dynamic link</a>
```